# How can I transfer ACL settings?

Tags: drupal, acl

I want to transfer ACL settings from one site to an other.
[image]

How can I export/import ACLs via SQL?

Or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: did you look at that civicrm_acl and similarly named tables?